# Explode url with specific value

Tags: php

I need some help about explode some url

The link is just like this

```
$link = 'http://example.com/networks/test.php?testid={CLICKID}&payid={PAYID}';
```

How to split the testid and payid and replace the {CLICKID} and {PAYID} with exact value?

It supposed to be something like this

http://example.com/networks/test.php?testid=a123456789&payid={205}

I have tried

```
list($mya, $test)       = explode("?", $link);     
list($myc, $testid)     = explode("=", $test);      

list($myb, $paid)       = explode("&", $link);         
list($myd, $payid)      = explode("=", $paid);
```

Comment: why not use [$_GET](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)?

Comment: `parse_url`, `parse_str`, replace values in resulting parameter array, `http_build_query` to create the new query string from that, and then just assemble the parts again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not "explode" the URL right:

```
$link = 'http://example.com/networks/test.php?testid={CLICKID}&payid={PAYID}';

list($mya, $getParams)  = explode("?", $link);        

list($param1, $param2)  = explode("&", $getParams);
list($param1, $testid)  = explode("=", $param1);
list($param2, $payid)    = explode("=", $param2);
```

However, if you want to parse the URL your php script runs in, I recommend using $_GET, as treyBake suggested:

```
$testid = $_GET['testid'];
$payid  = $_GET['payid'];
```